# How do you return data from a back end node js to front end html?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Im working with Firebase functions. I want to return data from a Node JS cloud function to to be able to use it with html /front end code.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
    response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

Comment: What does not work with the HTTPS Cloud Function form your question? Also note the possibility to use Callable Cloud Functions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Comment: Well, the function you have should return a response normally, are you getting any errors? Can you elaborate what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: @RafaelLemos My question is more conceptual. Im building a web app  using firebase database, auth.. etc.  I have a lot of code (Javascript) sitting/ running in the front end in the 'public'  folder. These Javascript code does various things gets data and send data from to firebase database. I want to start writing my code to the back end, so people are not able to see in the web browser using web dev tools. I was wondering if there is a way to write my code in node js and return the data the front end and use it with plain html. At the moment Im not using any front end libraries, just Javascri

Comment: @RenaudTarnec My question is more conceptual. Im building a web app  using firebase database, auth.. etc.  I have a lot of code (Javascript) sitting/ running in the front end in the 'public'  folder. These Javascript code does various things gets data and send data from to firebase database. I want to start writing my code to the back end, so people are not able to see in the web browser using web dev tools. I was wondering if there is a way to write my code in node js and return the data the front end and use it with plain html. At the moment Im not using any front end libraries

Comment: @JoseLopez Add that information to the question itself, as the question is implying that you are not able to use that particular code you shared due to some error.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that not all the Javscript code you have will be in a Cloud Function, code that directly interacts with your front end will still need to be in there, however, any code that directly operates with firebase can be transfered to a Cloud Functions.

You could use either [Callable Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), which can be called directly from your Javascript code but are hosted on the cloud, or [HTTP Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http) which are basically a HTTP request to an URL that sends you a response when it's done.

Cloud Functions also provides an [emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator) so you can test everything locally.

Before starting anything thought, I would recommend you to watch [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM) provided by Firebase that gives a really good intruction to Cloud Functions, so exactly what you are looking for.